# JavaScript - How to sort objects in array by online people, then by his rank permissions and then order alphabetically by name?

Tags: javascript

Heyo, i'm trying to render **REST API** for friends in **JSON**. I already have friends from database in one **array**, but i need to **sort** them for better sense. For example array looks like:

```
const friends = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hellbyte",
    "rank": "founder",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tess",
    "rank": "user",
    "online": false
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Katey",
    "rank": "admin",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "John",
    "rank": "globalmoderator",
    "online": false
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Andre",
    "rank": "admin",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Xyz",
    "rank": "user",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Nate",
    "rank": "premium",
    "online": false
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Berry",
    "rank": "premium",
    "online": false
  }
]
```

And i need to sort them by this **conditions**:

- Online is true

  - Rank is in this order: founder, admin, globalmoderator, premium, user
  - Alphabetically by name
- Online is false

  - Rank is in this order: founder, admin, globalmoderator, premium, user
  - Alphabetically by name

Now it should looks like:

```
const friends = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Hellbyte",
    "rank": "founder",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Andre",
    "rank": "admin",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Katey",
    "rank": "admin",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Xyz",
    "rank": "user",
    "online": true
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "John",
    "rank": "globalmoderator",
    "online": false
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Berry",
    "rank": "premium",
    "online": false
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Nate",
    "rank": "premium",
    "online": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tess",
    "rank": "user",
    "online": false
  }
]
```

How can i sort it like this? Please let me know how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: I don't have any code, i don't know how to write sort function well to do what i need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array#sort` and pass a custom comparator to compare `friend` based on `online` status, followed by `rank` order and at last by lexicographic-ally by `name`.

```js
const friends = [ { "id": 1, "name": "Hellbyte", "rank": "founder", "online": true }, { "id": 3, "name": "Tess", "rank": "user", "online": false }, { "id": 9, "name": "Katey", "rank": "admin", "online": true }, { "id": 5, "name": "John", "rank": "globalmoderator", "online": false }, { "id": 10, "name": "Andre", "rank": "admin", "online": true }, { "id": 19, "name": "Xyz", "rank": "user", "online": true }, { "id": 17, "name": "Nate", "rank": "premium", "online": false }, { "id": 25, "name": "Berry", "rank": "premium", "online": false } ],
    ranks = ["founder", "admin", "globalmoderator", "premium", "user"];
friends.sort((a,b) => b.online - a.online || ranks.indexOf(a.rank) - ranks.indexOf(b.rank) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log(friends);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the various online states and ranks for the order and sort first by `online`, then by `rank`and at last by the `name`.

this approach allows to have diffrent sort order for ranks, independently of the online status.

```js
var rank = { true: { founder: 1, admin: 2, globalmoderator: 3, premium: 4, user: 5 }, false: { founder: 1, admin: 2, globalmoderator: 3, premium: 4, user: 5 } },
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "Hellbyte", rank: "founder", online: true }, { id: 3, name: "Tess", rank: "user", online: false }, { id: 9, name: "Katey", rank: "admin", online: true }, { id: 5, name: "John", rank: "globalmoderator", online: false }, { id: 10, name: "Andre", rank: "admin", online: true }, { id: 19, name: "Xyz", rank: "user", online: true }, { id: 17, name: "Nate", rank: "premium", online: false }, { id: 25, name: "Berry", rank: "premium", online: false }];

data.sort((a, b) =>
    b.online - a.online ||
    rank[a.online][a.rank] - rank[b.online][b.rank] ||
    a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
);

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```